# Define_method rails mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Is it possible to write mailer methods with `define_method`,because i need almost similar methods,like
  `notify_user_approved` & `notify_user_rejected`

```
   %w(approved rejected).each do|meth|
      define_method("notify_user_#{meth}") do |user,subject|
        @url = user.email
        @user = user
        mail(to: @url, subject: subject)
      end
    end
```

`Notification` is my mailer class name

```
Notification.notify_user_rejected(User.last,'approved').deliver_now
```

i having `NoMethodError: undefined method`mail' for Notification:Class

when to try run my mailer

whole class

```
class Notification < ActionMailer::Base


 %w(approved rejected).each do|meth|
   define_method("notify_user_#{meth}") do |user,subject|
     @url = user.email
     @user = user
     mail(to: @url, subject: subject)
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: It should be possible Does your class inherit from `ActionMailer::Base`? could you show your whole class as well?

Comment: @BroiSatse,updated question